# How to specify an specific max value with 2 decimals in a div using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I want my textbox to allow the maximum value of 999.99, so after this the user is not allowed to type anymore. So far I can restrict the 2 decimal values using the following code:

```
$("#EstimatedDurationHrs").keyup(function (event) {
    if ((pointPos = this.value.indexOf('.')) >= 0)
        $(this).attr("maxLength", pointPos + 3);
    else
        $(this).removeAttr("maxLength");
});
```

But unfortunately I do not know how to prevent the user to type a value larger than 999.
Any advice would be really helpful, thank you.

Comment: parseFloat the value and test, then remove first or last digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with regex

```
$("#EstimatedDurationHrs").keyup(function (event) {
   if(/^\d{0,3}.\d{0,2}?$/.test($(this).val())) {
      console.log("valid");
   }else{
     console.log("notvalid");
   }

}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6etA/)